# Matrix representation of the derivative of a smooth function

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

> Let $V:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a smooth function and define the Hamiltonian function $H:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ (kinetic plus potential energy) by $$H(x,y):=\frac 12|y|^2+V(x).$$
> Prove that $c$ is a regular value of $H$ if and only if it is a regular value of $V$.

Look at the definition of regular values:

> Definition Let $U\subset \mathbb R^k$ be an open set and $f:U\to \mathbb R^l$ be a smooth function. An element $c\in \mathbb R^l$ is called a regular value of $f$ if, for all $p\in U$, we have
>
> $f(p)=c\implies df(p):\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^l$ is surjective.

In the definition, $f$ is a smooth function with the domain being a subset of $\mathbb R^k$. In our "Hamiltonian function" problem, the domain of the Hamilitonian function is  $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n$. There its derivative $dH$ is a function with the same domain and codomain. But what kind of matrix are we going to use to represent $dH$? Without this being answered, I can not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note $$dH(p,q)(x,y) = q\cdot y + dV(p)(x)$$ for all $(p,q), (x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$. Suppose $c$ is a regular value of $H$. Let $p \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $V(p) = c$. Then $H(p,0) = c$. Since $dH(p,0)$ is surjective, given $r \in \Bbb R$, there exists $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n$ such that $dH(p,0)(x,y) = r$, i.e., $dV(p)(x) = r$. Thus, $dV(p)$ is surjective. Since $p$ is an arbitrary point of $V^{-1}(c)$, $c$ is a regular value of $V$. Now try to prove the converse.

Comment: Is $q\cdot y$ the dot product? By the way how do you know the derivative of $\frac 12|y|^2$ at $q$ is $q\cdot y$?

Comment: Yes, $q\cdot y$ is the dot product of $q$ and $y$. To get the formula for $dH(p,q)(x,y)$, compute $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0} H(p + tx, q + ty)$.

Comment: I did try to calculate the limit, but how can I expand $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac 12 |q+ty|^2-\frac 12|q|^2}t$?

Comment: By the way, here is what I have got so far: Assume that c is a regular value of $V$. We want to show that c is also a regular value for $H$. $\forall (p,q)\in R^n\times R^n$, s.t. $H(p,q)=c$, Let's show $dH(p,q)$ is surj. Before we do that, let's utilize our hypothesis: Since H(p,q)=c, we have $\frac 12 |q|^2+V(p)=c$, but we want it to be of the form $V(p)=c$. What should we do next?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity consider the case n=1. $H(x,y)=y^2/2+V(x)$, $dH=ydy+V_xdx$ is a linear map in the tangent space whose matrix representation is the gradient:
$$\operatorname{grad}(H): (u,v)\mapsto V_xu+yv=\begin{bmatrix}V_x & y\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix}$$

For general n $$dH=\sum_{i=1}^ny^idy^i+\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial x^i}dx^i$$ whose matrix representation is $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial x^2} &\cdots \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial x^n} & y^1 &\cdots y^n\end{bmatrix}
$$